# Android Studio "Could not find aapt2-windows.jar" Error

Tags: android, android-studio

Hey there I'm making an app with minimum SdkVersion 14 and when I'm trying to build the project it says this:

> Could not find aapt2-windows.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.3.1-5013011).
>   Searched in the following locations: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.3.1-5013011/aapt2-3.3.1-5013011-windows.jar

But the problem is there is nothing on this page :(

It already has the "google()" in the gradle codes

and I haven't found any solution yet :(

Comment: Please Include  repositories {
      google() 
      jcenter()
  } in build.gradle file . Thank u

Comment: @erfann34 did you find any answer? I have the same problem